# Wacom tablet works but is not shown in settings

Tags: drivers, settings, tablet, wacom

My Wacom tablet works but it is not shown in the settings. Just a moment ago, it was there but now, the tablet is gone from the settings and it says "No tablet detected".

I have restarted my computer twice but it didn't bring the tablet back to the settings.
I am running Ubuntu 16.04.
Is there a way to make the GUI for settings work?

There are already few of threads here asking basically the same question but they are all quite old and none of them is answered.

Comment: Is this a usb tablet? If so please [edit] your post to include the output of `lsusb`